# ViewPager swipe doesn't work with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I want to implement a simple swipe navigation using a ViewPager with fragments that hold and manage a RecyclerView.

The Fragments are created and can be switched using `setCurrentItem()`, but you cannot swipe left or right to switch pages. The ViewPager seems to ignore any swipe gesture.

My Activity layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                  ...                 />

</FrameLayout>
```

I populate the ViewPager using a `FragmentPagerAdapter` in my `onCreate()` like so:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
       @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           switch (position) {
               case 0:
                   return new Dummy2Fragment();

               case 1:
                   return new Dummy2Fragment();

               default:
                   return null;
           }
        }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           return 2;
       }

       @Override
       public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
           return "Dataset " + (position + 1);
       }
   });
```

The fragment layout is a simple `FrameLayout` which wraps a RecyclerView:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_material_light"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The adapter and the layout manager are set in the fragment's `onCreateView`:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 6, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
```

---

**Edit #1**

I think I did not ask my question clear enough.
I have a working Pager with a working TabLayout that is populated by a 'FragmentPagerAdapter', meaning that Fragments are properly created and the tab layout displays a clickable tab for each item. Every Fragment in this ViewPager displays a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`.

However, the ViewPager doesn't seem to receive any swipe gesture, You can change the current selected position via the `TabLayout`, but not by swiping for example from left to right.
It looks like the `RecyclerView` consumes all swipe events regardless of the layout direction, which is set to `vertical`.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/tabs-with-swipe-views/#more-79

Answer (score 2):

You can use tablayout with Viewpager like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Also set

```
   tabLayout = (TabLayout) rv.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
   tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

and Method setupWithViewPager is like

```
  private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
      adapter = new Adapter(getChildFragmentManager());
      adapter.addFragment(new MatesListFragment(), "Mates");
      adapter.addFragment(new FavoursListFragment(), "Favours");
      adapter.addFragment(new FavemeListFragment(), "FavMe");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


 class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList();

    public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

     public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
         return POSITION_NONE;
     }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

In MatesListFragment, FavoursListFragment etc. you have your RecyclerView layout

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think you misunderstood my question, I was wondering why the ViewPagers swipe functionality isn't working. I also have a version of this activity containing a tab layout, but swipe gestures are ignored there either.